# Will glucose meter strips be safe in the Airplane Cargo Hold?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, health

I will be taking my glucose meter strips with me and need to know if they will be safe in the cargo area.

Comment: Looking at the notes with my CareSens N strips, you should store your strips between 1° and 30° Celsius, so I'd guess they'd be all right in the aircraft hold. But why not take them in the cabin?

Comment: Since checked luggage can be lost or delayed, it's generally considered inadvisable to check medical equipment. Especially since the strips are small, it seems like it would make far more sense to bring them in your carry-on so that you have them during the flight and after you land.

Comment: Thank you, but my trip is for 10 days and I need to take 4 boxes to make sure that I have enough when I am gone.  Along with my other supplies for my meter's that I need along with my insulin.

Answer (score 4):

There are two aspects to this, risk of damage to the strips, and risk of damage to you if your checked luggage is lost, stolen, or even substantially delayed.

Check the package for temperature range and any other limitations on storage for the strips you are using.

For anything medically necessary, you need to have enough in your carry-on and under your direct control to survive without affecting your health until you can replace what was in your checked luggage. Depending on where you are traveling and the nature of the item that may mean consulting a local doctor to get a new prescription then getting that prescription filled. At the other extreme you may only need a few days supply if the item is sold over-the-counter at your destination.